# Matching 2 Data Set rows with similar column headings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting, power-query

I have 2 data sets A-Q (left) and U-AA (right)

I am trying to match the rows on the (right) U-AA with the rows on the (left) A-Q

Once a record on the right matches the first like record to the left then it would skip to the next one to find.
I manually inserted rows on the first few to give a visual of what I am trying to accomplish

My like headings on both data sets are highlighted in red

([image]

[image]

I am trying to attached the sample excel file but this may not be allowed.  Trying DropBox
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/b7i8aggn7tlt5yg9hh321/MatchRows-060321.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=a2zkfn867nyf4mfubdkqemgc4

Comment: Many won't download a file from the internet.  You could post your data as text.  For those who will download a file, the procedure is for you to upload it to some public sharing site (eg OneDrive, DropBox) and then post a link in your question.

Comment: Why not just use a filter?  You can use an Advanced Filter if you want the results someplace else